# How to Show taxonomies terms custom field value using ACF plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy-terms

I have used Advance Custom Field (ACF) wordpress plugin to add custom filed on Woocommerce -> Product -> Categories form.

Right now i can't able to print that field value on categories page.

Please see this screen shot to know field slug name and other details -> http://nimb.ws/BsSiJO  and help me to show that field value on categories page.

Thanks,
Ketan.

Comment: Did you able to add category successfully? I mean at the backend?

Comment: Yes i have added category successfully in the backend side. Now i want to show that custom filed text below the woocommerce categories name.

Comment: at the frontend right?

Comment: Yes in front end. So my question is that How to show ACF plugin taxonomies_term value in front end side ?

Comment: Please include the relevant code for what you have tried already. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

**Display a field**

```
<p><?php the_field('field_name', $term); ?></p>
```

**Retrieve a field**

```
<?php

$variable = get_field('field_name', 'product-cat_23');

// do something with $variable

?>
```

**Finding the term related to the current post**

```
<?php

// load all 'category' terms for the post
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');


// we will use the first term to load ACF data from
if( !empty($terms) ) {

    $term = array_pop($terms);

    $custom_field = get_field('category_image', $term );

    // do something with $custom_field
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But above code i also see on ACF document but that cant help me.

So please review this my field http://nimb.ws/BsSiJO and Can you please make perfect code for me.

Thanks.